# Dealing with \n issues

Tags: c

```
int main(void){
char* line = "CCCCCCC\nC+\nC++";
char* line2 = "a\nb\nc";
printf("%s\n", line);
printf("%s\n", line2);
}
```

This code correctly prints: CCCCCCC

C+

C++

a

b

c

Now my issue is this, I am working on rgrep function implemented without string.h. Below is the main from the code im working on, which I am not to modify.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
   if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <PATTERN>\n", argv[0]);
        return 2;
    }

/* we're not going to worry about long lines */
char buf[MAXSIZE];

while (!feof(stdin) && !ferror(stdin)) {
    if (!fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), stdin)) {
        break;
   }
   if (rgrep_matches(buf, argv[1])) {
       fputs(buf, stdout);
       fflush(stdout);
   }
 }

if(ferror(stdin)) {
   perror(argv[0]);
   return 1;
   }

return 0;
}

int rgrep_matches(char *line, char *pattern){
   printf("%s", line);
   return 0;
}
```

Now when I run the above code on test test file containing the same strings as the above code "CCCCCCC\nC+\nC++","a\nb\nc".

Whys does the above code output:

CCCCCCC\nC+\nC++

a\nb\nc

Clearly ignoring the '\n'.

When the test code built in a different file posted at the top of the page prints:

CCCCCCC

C+

C++

a

b

c

What is going on here?

Comment: Are you actually inputting a `\n` or is it a real newline character (the enter key)? The two characters `\n` in a string that isn't a string literal are just that, two characters. There's nothing special about that sequence in text, it's only special when being compiled as a string literal as in your first example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The C compiler recognizes `’\n’` in text constants *in your code* as special sequences, and translates them in the correct <kbd>RET</kbd> sequences for the machine you are on.
If you read a `\` and a following `n` from a file, they are just two normal characters, and *your program* would need to process them special if you want that.